# Proper use of a table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a table `my_ids` with single column `id`. Next, I have a table-valued function `fn_getMatches(id)`. What I want is to iterate through table `my_ids` and for each `id` call function `fn_getMatches(id)` and aggregate all results in one table. How do I do that without explicit loop?

I tried:

```
select *
from my_ids ids
     full outer join fn_getMatches(ids.id) on 1=2
where ids.id is null
```

But it returns:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   The multi-part identifier "ids.id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having no idea what the function does, or what results you expect, maybe try:

```
select * -- name your columns!
from dbo.my_ids AS ids -- use schema prefix!
cross apply dbo.fn_getMatches(ids.id); -- use schema prefix!
```

Removed the `WHERE` clause and the `ON` criteria from your initial attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
        FROM my_ids ids
        CROSS APPLY fn_getMatches(ids.id)
```

I don't quite *get* your WHERE clause, since it would seem to mean that you know the value of `ids.id` in advance and it's always `NULL`.

Comment: it's sort of was a trick together with 1=2 condition so to get only results from function. Anyway, your answer is correct, Aaron was a few seconds faster, I wish I could accept both:)