# Why can't one join with a table returned from a table valued function?

Tags: sql-server

The equivalent of an inner join with table valued functions (TVF) is to use `CROSS APPLY` (one [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429227/proper-use-of-a-table-valued-function) inner join with a TVF).

I'm wondering why SQL Server disallows joins with the return values of a TVF. Specifically, how is doing a `CROSS APPLY` on a TVF different than inner joining with a temporary table? Is there a difference in how SQL Server defines the return table of a TVF and a temporary table?

Comment: With an inner join both tables are stable throughout. With `apply` the contents of the table expression on the right can change for each row in the left.

Comment: If we had a short code sample of what you were trying to do, we could compose a better answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith That answer makes very good sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblFoo
INNER JOIN (fnGetTable(tblFoo.someValue)
```

`fnGetTable` returns a new table for **each** value of `tblFoo.someValue`. So rather than joining with one table, you're joining with many.

I think ultimately this has to do with temporary tables and db tables being constant objects. Table valued functions don't necessarily return the same table object each time.

Answer (score 3):

> How is doing a CROSS APPLY on a TVF different than inner joining with
>   a temporary table?

You **can** join a TVF, however you **can not** use columns from the joining table within the TVF call:

```
DECLARE @directions VARCHAR(MAX) = 'N, S, W, E' 

SELECT  a.StreetName, s.Value
FROM dbo.Address a 
JOIN dbo.SplitByToken(@directions, ',') s ON a.Direction = s.Value
```

Here the table valued function creates a table based on a string-list separated by a token. This query would not have a problem, as the result of the table function is known and doesn't change per result of the joining table. It runs once and the resulting table is joined to `Address`.

It's when the TVF is being used with a column from the joining table that the `cross apply` must be used instead of `join`.

```
SELECT  a.ZIP, g.Long, g.Lat
FROM dbo.Address a 
CROSS APPLY dbo.GeoLocation(a.ZIP) g
```

Here the Geo Location is calculated based on the table we are using at the time of calculation, and the function needs to be called once per row of the `Address` table.