# SQL Server - Split a field into 4 columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a function that split an address line into 4 columns when it encounters a carriage return. It is a multi statement table valued function. How can I use it to split the address line field from the address table? I cannot use joins because it uses the table fields as paramaters. Any clue?

```
SELECT [ID], [ADDRESS_LINE] FROM [dbo].[ADDRESS]
```

The function needs 3 arguments: Address_ID, Address string and separator which is carriage return.

```
[dbo].[fn_Split_Address](ID, ADDRESS_LINE, CHAR(13))
```

Example to help understand:

```
SELECT A.Addresse_ID, A.Adresse_1, A.Adresse_2, A.Adresse_3,
A.Adresse_4 FROM RE7_Pass.[dbo].[fn_Split_Address](888999, '10
Burlington street' + CHAR(13) + 'Chicago'+ CHAR(13) +
'Illinois',CHAR(13)) AS A
```

The result should be as below:

[image]

Comment: Use CROSS APPLY

Comment: Look at the CROSS APPLY version of the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796298/why-cant-one-join-with-a-table-returned-from-a-table-valued-function

Comment: You should consider a better function for splitting. A multi-statement table valued function is usually slower than even a scalar function. My guess is it has a loop in there also. Here is a set based splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Pawan's comment:

```
SELECT A.[ID],
       A.[ADDRESS_LINE],
       SA.Address1,
       SA.Address2,
       SA.Address3,
       SA.Address4
FROM [dbo].[ADDRESS] A
     CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Split_Address] (A.ID, A.Address_Line, CHAR(13)) SA;
```

The documentation on the [`FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) clause explains well on how to get data from a TVF:
[Using APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#using-apply)

> Both the left and right operands of the APPLY operator are table expressions. The main difference between these operands is that the right_table_source can use a table-valued function that takes a column from the left_table_source as one of the arguments of the function. The left_table_source can include table-valued functions, but it cannot contain arguments that are columns from the right_table_source.

It also gives further examples further down the page, at [using CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#l-using-cross-apply). The example they provide being:

```
USE master;  
GO  
SELECT dbid, object_id, query_plan   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle);   
GO
```

Comment: not much of an expansion... you could add some content from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to make it a better answer.

Comment: Probably better to go with the more recent document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#k-using-apply)